# Rethinkdb SIGTERM, shutting down

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

I'm running RethinkDB in Docker. Everything was working REALLY well for a while until we moved to a new datacenter (but im not sure if this is related to the move at all). Here's what is going on.

I start the rethinkdb container and everything runs well for a while. After some amount of time (it varies between an hour or more) I see the following in the Docker logs (highlighted in yellow):

[image: RethinkDB SIGTERM]

I have absolutely no idea why it receives a SIGTERM from the system randomly. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I am adding the snippet of the logfile for the SIGTERMs. There doesn't seem to be any kind of pattern according to the timestamps.

```
2015-07-15T16:15:02.888762613 663165.661585s notice: Server got SIGTERM from pid 0, uid 0; shutting down...
2015-07-17T17:02:11.562306701 13322.914561s notice: Server got SIGTERM from pid 0, uid 0; shutting down...
2015-07-19T18:31:12.499022237 96786.220054s notice: Server got SIGTERM from pid 0, uid 0; shutting down...
2015-07-20T13:52:44.493304030 69690.608865s notice: Server got SIGTERM from pid 0, uid 0; shutting down...
```

**EDIT 2:** I ran RethinkDB outside of Docker and I see this in the logs: **error: worker process failed to resynchronize with main process**. Not sure if it's anything to be concerned about. It does not appear to affect the RethinkDB instance at all (all clients remained connected).

```
2015-07-21T06:53:10.663375859 0.116098s info: Automatically using cache size of 10702 MB
2015-07-21T06:53:10.676277261 0.128998s notice: Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
2015-07-21T06:53:10.684504354 0.137225s notice: Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
2015-07-21T06:53:10.685485550 0.138206s notice: Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
2015-07-21T06:53:10.686313405 0.139034s notice: Listening on addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.42.1, 192.151.151.122, ::1, fe80::1879:43ff:fe5e:bdb2%34, fe80::62eb:69ff:fe07:d986%2, fe80::b837:f2ff:fecd:d5cd%4
2015-07-21T06:53:10.686316632 0.139037s notice: Server ready, "0aa312e817ef_nrx" 069ac5b3-9f43-4bbe-9022-c1f006790e99
2015-07-21T06:53:11.558116243 1.010837s error: worker process failed to resynchronize with main process
2015-07-21T06:53:11.558122179 1.010843s notice: A newer version of the RethinkDB server is available: 2.0.4. You can read the changelog at <https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/releases>.
```

**EDIT 3:** I found another issue here that I think may be the real problem. The rethink adapter (in the app) is keeping the connections to the DB server established which is exhausting the available file descriptors/ports in the system. Here is an example printout of an `lsof`. **NOTE** this is only a short list. There are hundreds/thousands of these kept open when multiple people use the system

```
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  201u    IPv4 0x53153575d33d64bb       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61041->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  202u    IPv4 0x53153575d33fa65b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61053->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  203u    IPv4 0x53153575dd6a5d8b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61043->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  204u    IPv4 0x53153575bff6717b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61044->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  206u    IPv4 0x53153575d33e54bb       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61049->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  207u    IPv4 0x53153575d33ef4bb       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61050->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  208u    IPv4 0x53153575d33f2a4b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61051->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  209u    IPv4 0x53153575c333a17b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61054->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  210u    IPv4 0x53153575d33b47fb       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61056->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  211u    IPv4 0x53153575d33de17b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61057->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  212u    IPv4 0x53153575d33f065b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61058->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  213u    IPv4 0x53153575bff67a4b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61059->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  216u    IPv4 0x53153575dd68f31b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61062->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
node    11633 [username_ommitted]  217u    IPv4 0x53153575dd675a4b       0t0      TCP 192.168.1.142:61063->[RETHINK_IP]:28015 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: feels like logrotate or something of the sort. Can you monitor the time it happens and see if there's a pattern? In any case it does look like the host is killing something... (might even be longrunning processes being killed by a monitoring daemon or sorts) Have you checked your hoster/ops ?

Comment: @Gekkie Yea I will try to grab the timestamp from the logs. Does rethinkdb have it's own log rotation built in? I'm assuming it does. Any way to check the config on that?

Comment: you can `docker stats container_id` the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stats/ or get into the container `docker exec -it container_id bash` the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/ and debug/monitor/check

Comment: @Gekkie I added the logfile output. There doesn't seem to be any kind of pattern :/

Comment: Could you post actual logfile text rather than *pictures* of logfiles?  This will generally make it easier for people to find the question via search engines if they run into the same problem, and it makes life easier for people who are trying to help you as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @haggy you mentioned changing datacenters, did you also change the host / config of any kind? I've been running various loads in production for over a year and havent seen anything like this... Also, can you reproduce locally with the same image? (i.e. by proxying a copy of the live traffic to the internal / debug container? That way you should at least be able to reproduce right?

Comment: @Gekkie Sorry about the image, I updated it with text. As far as config goes, I did not change anything. Rethink is running in a docker container which inherently keeps the config within the container identical. I started a test where I am running RethinkDB in a screen session instead of in Docker to see if it happens outside of docker as well.

Comment: @Gekkie I updated the question again because I noticed something new in the logs while RethinkDB was running outside of docker. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you do a ```docker ps $rethinkDb-docker-container-id``` to see if there is a single process or multiple? It might be docker is killing the main process due to the fact that somehwhere along the line rethinkdb is misbehaving and shutting down the root process (after starting another) Are you running rethinkdb in the foreground? You might want to try to start it via a supervisord (or something of the sort) to see if that helps?

Comment: @Gekkie Sorry for the lack of response. I managed to get away on vacation :) So, I think there's a bigger issue with this. I am seeing that running `lsof` to get open connections to the DB shows that rethink adapter is keeping the connections to the DB established even though im closing them after the query. I'm adding an exmaple `lsof` dump to the original question. I have no idea what it is keeping this connections established... :(

Comment: @haggy seems rethinkdb might have some internal problems? It doesnt seem to be related to docker in anycase. You might want to look at [#issue1928](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1928) or some type of google-fu to look for filedescriptor problems in regards to rethinkdb

Comment: @Gekkie I agree that this is a Rethink issue at this point. I'm hoping a rethink dev will see this :/

Comment: Hey @haggy, do you happen to never close the connection to RethinkDB in your code? Or are you starting new connections every time you make a query without closing them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and believe it to be caused by not closing database connections (as you note in your `EDIT 3`). I'm using RethinkDB in a expressjs app and followed there middleware example from [here](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs/blob/master/todo-angular-express-promise/app.js#L15) but I always terminate the request-response cycle within my controllers without calling `next()`, meaning the closeConnection middleware was never being reached.